# Does a category where binary products commute with binary coproducts necessarily have biproducts?

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

Given a category $\mathcal{C}$ with binary products and binary coproducts for which the canonical comparison morphism $(A \times B) + (C \times D) \to (A+C) \times (B + D)$ is an isomorphism for any four objects $A, B, C, D \in \mathcal{C}$, must $\mathcal{C}$ have zero morphisms (enriched over pointed sets) and binary biproducts (which make sense in any category with zero morphisms)?

Recall that if $\mathcal{C}$ has zero morphisms, then there is a canonical morphism $A+B \to A \times B$ induced by the identities on $A$ and $B$ and the zero morphisms $0_{A,B}:A \to B$ and $0_{B,A}:B \to A$. If that morphism is an isomorphism, then one calls $A+B \cong A \times B$ a biproduct of $A$ and $B$.

If $\mathcal{C}$ has a zero object, then the claim is easily seen to be true (just let $B=C=0$). This is essentially the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument).

If $\mathcal{C}$ does not have a zero object, then the Eckmann-Hilton argument does not apply.

Comment: Have you tried freely appending a zero object? It seems to me that this might be done without breaking any of the givens.

Answer (score 2):

For any objects $A$ and $B$, consider the composition $$0_{A,B}:A\xrightarrow{(i_0,i_1)} (A+B)\times (B+A)\cong (A\times B)+(B\times A)\xrightarrow{(p_1,p_0)} B.$$ Here $(i_0,i_1)$ is the map that is the first inclusion $A\to A+B$ on the first coordinate and the second inclusion $A\to B+A$ on the second coordinate, and dually for $(p_1,p_0)$.  I claim that these are zero morphisms.  Indeed, just observe that $0_{A,B}$ is a composition of three natural transformations (with respect to both $A$ and $B$) and thus is a natural transformation (specifically, a natural transformation between the two projection functors $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$).  Naturality with respect to $B$ says exactly that $f0_{A,B}=0_{A,C}$ for any $f:B\to C$ and similarly naturality with respect to $A$ gives closure under compositions on the other side.

(In fact, this argument does not require the morphism $(A+C) \times (B + D) \to (A \times B) + (C \times D)$ used in the definition of $0_{A,B}$ to be inverse to the canonical morphism; it just requires the existence of *any* natural transformation $(A+B)\times (B+A)\to (A\times B)+(B\times A)$ (natural in both $A$ and $B$).  This is reminiscent of how to get a zero object, you just need there to exist a morphism from a terminal object to an initial object.)